# Achieve Dynamic Animation in angular 4 to move to next section on click

Tags: angular, animation, rxjs

In my application I want to scroll to next section on click of an arrow.

> Reference [website](https://wavespace.ey.com/)

In above website if you click on the arrow it performs `transform:translate3d(a,b,c)` to move to next section where in only 'b' value changes.

Note: My current viewport height is 949px; which is I am calculating dynamically

I tried like below in my application:

```
 moveToNextSection() {

    $('.bfs-scroll-container').animate({
      'opacity': '949'
  }, {
      step: function (now, fx) {
          $(this).css({'transform': 'translate3d(0px, -' + now + 'px, 0px)'});
      },
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'linear',
  }, 'linear');

  }
```

which is working fine; however I want to go with angular approach. NO JQUERY.

I tried below with Observable:

```
  moveToNextSection() {
     const sectionScrollTop = this.document.documentElement.clientHeight; //949
     //const interval = sectionScrollTop / 1000;
     Observable.interval(1).subscribe((val) => {
       console.log(val);
       this.renderer.setStyle(this.scrollMe.nativeElement, 'transform', `translate3d(0px,-${val}px,0px)`);
    });

}
```

which is working but very slow and obv wrong approach.

Also I am not sure how to achieve this dynamic animation using `@angular/animations`.

Note: The above mention site has some different HTML layout; we have to follow exactly same.  So I don't want to use  `window.scrollTo()`. 
Want to achieve similar animation to move to next section what above website is doing.

Kindly suggest me how to achieve this in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with following solution using renderer 2  :

HTML :

```
 <div class="bfs-scroll-container" #scrollMe>
      <app-about-company></app-about-company>
      <app-about-bfs></app-about-bfs>
 </div>
```

typescript :

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Component, Inject, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
    import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-main',
      templateUrl: './main.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
    })
    export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

      @ViewChild('scrollMe') scrollMe: ElementRef;
      @ViewChild('scrollTop') scrollTop: ElementRef;

      constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private renderer: Renderer2) {

      }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      moveToNextSection() {
              const elementLength = this.scrollMe.nativeElement.children.length;

               const elementTopPosition = this.scrollMe.nativeElement.children[this.index].offsetTop;  //pass index of your child component where you want to scroll to instrad of this.index
               this.renderer.setStyle(this.scrollMe.nativeElement, 'transform', `translate3d(0px,-${elementTopPosition}px,0px)`);
               this.renderer.setStyle(this.scrollTop.nativeElement, 'opacity', `1`);
       }

 }
```